# vendor autoload functioning on localhost, not working on EB

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been testing the tumblr library on my local site, and everything works as expected. However, on uploading to AWS I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tumblr\API\Client' not found in /var/app/current/tumblr.php on line 15
```

With the following code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
include('dbcon.php');

use Tumblr\API;

$consumerKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

$client = new Tumblr\API\Client(
  $consumerKey,
  $consumerSecret,
  'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'xxxxxxxxxx'
);
```

Is there a reason the load would be working on local, but not on AWS?

Comment: It looks like you haven't uploaded the 'vendor' directory to AWS. Make sure that it get's transferred, and it's in the same location os on local machine.

Comment: I just checked, and the vendor file is not getting uploaded properly, yet all other files are, why would this happen?

Comment: It would happen if it's not committed...

Comment: After looking, one of the autoload libraries including a `.gitignore` file, preventing all other libraries to be committed.